# R or Mysql: Change values of a column to null if they are not present in another row of the same dataframe

Tags: mysql, r

I am retrieving a table from the mysql database into r but I need to change the values of class1 and class2  **to null** if the values within them are **not present in the column school**. I am unable to do that. Is there any way of doing it either in R or as a select query in MySQL? In other words, convert those values to null which do not appear in another row of the same table.

Here is my table:

[image: Here is my table:]

And here is how I want to retrieve it as:
[image: And here is how I want to retrieve it as:]

Comment: You can easily do this in a query. Please show all tables and columns. It is also strange data storage here. What does *class1*, *class2*, ... mean? If they carry school indicators, wouldn't *school* be redundant?

Comment: Actually, this is only example data, the real data is huge. This is the only table that is needed and no, the column school is unique.

Comment: class 1 and class two are the categories under which the school falls.

Comment: In R you would not be changing to NULL but rather to NA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT
    s.school,
    CASE WHEN q1.class1 IS NOT NULL THEN NULL ELSE s.class1 END AS class1,
    CASE WHEN q2.class2 IS NOT NULL THEN NULL ELSE s.class2 END AS class2
FROM
    schools AS s
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT class1 FROM schools WHERE class1 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT school FROM schools)) AS q1 ON s.class1 = q1.class1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT class2 FROM schools WHERE class2 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT school FROM schools)) AS q2 ON s.class2 = q2.class2

    ORDER BY
        s.school
```

[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d76c4/1)